# How to Share an image in social share using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-social-plugins, addthis

i am trying to implement the Social Share Button In My Website,There i want to Share  dynamic Image  based on the user selection.

I using the Addthis Plugin,If there any other option to image sharing

My code:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/ShopifyScripts/addthis_widget.js")"></script>

         <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style addthis_32x32_style">
             <a class="addthis_button_facebook"></a>
             <a class="addthis_button_twitter"></a>
             <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share"></a>
             <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_share"></a>
             <a class='addthis_button_tumblr'></a>
             <a class="addthis_button_email"></a>
             @* <a class="addthis_button_compact"></a>
         <a class="addthis_counter addthis_bubble_style"></a>
         </div>
```

Please help me to find out the solution.

Thanks advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as i understand you need to change url dynamically so yes you can do it with addthis [More info](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/125634-setting-the-url-to-share#.UtAZWJ5_tzo)

Generally you need to set attribute addthis:url and share this will know which url you are sharing